# SOA and WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture, soa

I want to use SOA architecture for my next project. Also, I want to use WCF Data Services for data access layer. For example, the user wants to receive the documents for a certain date. We call the WCF service (Service Layer) to retrieve the documents

```
public ActionResult GetDocumentByDate(DateTime date)
{
    var request = // here create request object;
    var documentsDto = _documentService.GetDocument(request);
   ...
}
```

In the WCF service we call bussines layer (BL):

```
public class DocumentService:IDocumentService
{
     public IEnumerable<DocumentDto> GetDocumentsByDate(DocumentsByDateRequest request)
     {
          // call GetDocumentsByDate from DocumentLogic
     }
}

public class DocumentLogic
{
    public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocumentsByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        // call DAL
    }
}
```

I want to use WCF Data Services for getting data. I haven't worked with this tech.

**It is good practice to hide WCF Data Services behind service layer or they should be available, just SL accesses the data through the WCF Data Services?**

In this case, the outside world will be seen WCF services and WCF Data Services.
**In accordance with the example, where better to do validation?**

**And finally the general question, what is your impression of the WCF Data Services?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that DataServices is a cool technology but I think that hiding them from users is a bad idea. Actually you are not really hiding the service, you just not call explicitly.. If you want to use dataservices you can just call the service from your asp .net code. If you want you can manage and restrict your data (entities) using specific methods in the dataservice.. As I guess you are using EF :)

I think the best place to do validation is in your asp .net code (before you create the request of course).